# pgfgantt: reduce bottom margin

Tags: spacing, pgfgantt

I am using `pgfgantt` to produce a fairly ordinary gantt chart (with the only exception that it is generated via the `csvsimple` package which is also the reason for the missing MWE ;)
My Problem is that `pgfgantt` adds a rather large vertical space at the bottom end after the last line (about half a line or so?). This is also visible in the documentation and has nothing to do with the specifics of my document.

In a true table I would simply write something like `\\[-1em]` as terminator of the last line, but this obviously does not work with `pgfgantt`.
What's the easiest way to reduce the space between the last line and the bottom border of that chart?

Comment: Where exactly is the space you want to erase? Is it somewhere inside the gantt chart? Can you somehow show us using a picture at least? If it is between the gantt chart and the following text, you could just put `\vspace{-1em}\par` after `\end{ganttchart}`.

Comment: Why does the use of `csvsimple` prevent you from providing an MWE?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the options of the  standalone class worked for me

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={0pt -6pt 0pt 0pt}]{standalone}
```